# graphical diff tool with image output?

Tags: xml, diff

Is there a graphical diff tool for Linux that can output an image showing the diff?  I'm used to using meld.

I'm trying to diff XML and produce a visual diff for when the XML is different.

Answer (score 2):

kdiff3 is my favorite and should look similiar to meld and it works in windows also. But why isn't meld working for you, it should work in linux also.